# SQL query to add a column and to popluate it with values while running a query only, if its possible

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help while writing a query. So I have a table with me "Society", it has following columns Id, Firstname, Lastname. And it is populated by multiple rows with some rows having same lastname, and some having distinct lastname. So how to write a query to add a new column in the same table using a query only, say the name of the new column is Status, so value of status for all rows having common lastname as 'FAMILY', and value of Status for rows having distinct lastname as "SINGLE". I am new at this sql business, this is kind of my homework. So all helpful replies are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You should include some attempt in your question, particularly if this is homework.

Comment: I have not made any correct attempts on this, since I am new at this. I just have a table created , not sure how to proceed from there. ?

Comment: You should at least post examples of what data you have, and what outcome you would expect for exactly that data. Provide SQL commands for the table structure and the data. It'd be best, if you could provide a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) for your case.

Comment: It sounds like you are not trying to add a column to the table, but rather one in the output of your query that is not the same as one in the table itself?

Comment: I wish I could give a sql query for you here Kaushik, but remember, in S.O, if you don't seem to have made any attempt to solve your problem, it is considered by many of us as not worth answering. So, show us atleast some attempt to prove that you consider your homework seriously.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: SELECT FNAME,
LNAME,
DOB,
CASE 
AK.TOTAL WHEN '1' THEN 'SINGLE'
ELSE THEN 'FAMILY'
END
AS STATUS
FROM EMPNAME 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT LNAME,COUNT(LNAME)AS TOTAL
FROM EMPNAME
GROUP BY LNAME)AS AK
ON AK.LNAME=EMPNAME.LNAME;                                                     When I am trying to do this, to get a column added in the output of my query, for Status=either 'family' or 'single'......I get a error ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table (no constraints whatsoever) and a few sample rows:

```
SQL> create table society
  2    (id        number,
  3     firstname varchar2(20),
  4     lastname  varchar2(20)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into society (id, firstname, lastname)
  2    select 1, 'Little', 'Foot'  from dual union
  3    select 2, 'Big'   , 'Foot'  from dual union
  4    select 3, 'Mickey', 'Mouse' from dual union
  5    select 4, 'Minnie', 'Mouse' from dual union
  6    select 5, 'Chris' , 'Rea'   from dual union
  7    select 6, 'Katie' , 'Melua' from dual;

6 rows created.

SQL> select * From society order by id;

        ID FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Little               Foot
         2 Big                  Foot
         3 Mickey               Mouse
         4 Minnie               Mouse
         5 Chris                Rea
         6 Katie                Melua

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

In order to add another column, use ALTER TABLE command:

```
SQL> alter table society add status varchar2(10);

Table altered.
```

Finally, update the newly added column. A simple query which does that relies on counting number of same lastnames. All lastnames whose count is greater than 1 are the "family" (while the rest is "single"):

```
SQL> select lastname, count(*) cnt
  2  from society
  3  group by lastname;

LASTNAME                    CNT
-------------------- ----------
Foot                          2   --> family
Rea                           1   --> single
Melua                         1   --> single
Mouse                         2   --> family

SQL>
```

Using the above `SELECT`, perform update; `CASE` will decide which status to apply:

```
SQL> update society s set
  2    s.status = (select case when x.cnt > 1 then 'FAMILY'
  3                            else 'SINGLE'
  4                       end
  5                from (select s1.lastname, count(*) cnt
  6                      from society s1
  7                      group by s1.lastname
  8                     ) x
  9                where x.lastname = s.lastname
 10               );

6 rows updated.

SQL> select * from society order by id;

        ID FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME             STATUS
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Little               Foot                 FAMILY
         2 Big                  Foot                 FAMILY
         3 Mickey               Mouse                FAMILY
         4 Minnie               Mouse                FAMILY
         5 Chris                Rea                  SINGLE
         6 Katie                Melua                SINGLE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have provided you guys with some blueprint or the attempts I had made on this. Okay so my table "Society" is like :